# Need help sorting out this movement function

Tags: java

Hi guys just wondering if you could help me out, could you tell me what i am doing wrong here, what i am trying to do is add 1 if r is typed and subtract 1 if L is typed for both the lower and upper cases. but the position keeps returning the original. please help!!

```
    int position = 0;
    System.out.print("move: ");
    String car = Global.keyboard.nextLine();
    if (car == "r/")
        position =  + 1;
    if (car == "R")
        position = +1;
    if (car == "l")
        position =  -1;
    if (car == "L")
        position = -1;
        System.out.print(position);
```

Comment: Use `String.equals` to compare Strings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: Most of the answers mention that `position = +1;` should be `position += 1;`, yet no-one mentioned the preferred way of `position++;`.

Comment: Also, what happens when you don't press `r`, `R`, `l` or `L`? Did you notice that you execute all of the `if`s regardless of which key was pressed? I've taken that into account, should you need another point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
int position = 0;
System.out.print("move: ");
String car = Global.keyboard.nextLine();
if (car.equals("r"))
    position += 1;
if (car.equals("R"))
    position += 1;
if (car.equals("l"))
    position -= 1;
if (car.equals("L"))
    position -= 1;
    System.out.print(position);
```

Comment: `car` appears to be a `String`, not a `char`. As stated in the question: `String car = Global.keyboard.nextLine();`

Comment: Still incorrect, he wants to create a running total (as specified in the question) but you are assigning the values of +/-1 depending on certain conditions.

Comment: Can you please explain ur self, I dint understand last comment

Comment: He wants to create a running total, re-read the question for further clarification.

Comment: Yeah! just got that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 1 liner, use this:

```
position += car.equalsIgnoreCase("r") ? 1 : car.equalsIgnoreCase("l") ? -1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use one of these styles :

```
position += 1
position -= 1
```

or

```
position = position + 1
position = position - 1
```

to add or subtract 1 from a value.  Currently you're just assigning it the value + / - 1.

Comment: while in this case using `+=1` and `-=1` is better (because then changing the amount is easier), you really ought to at least mention that they could use `++` and `--` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace every car == "something" with car.equals("something")

Like this:

```
String car = Global.keyboard.nextLine();
if (car.equals("r"))
    position =  + 1;
if (car.equals("R"))
    position = +1;
if (car.equals("l"))
    position =  -1;
if (car.equals("L"))
    position = -1;
    System.out.print(position);
```

Comment: I think you typo'd on `"r/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple `if`s (that should be `if - else` statements, so you don't cheack each one in every case) and `String`s, remember that you can `switch` a `char`:

```
int position = 0;
//int dx = 1; For this case, the explanation is in a comment below.
System.out.print("move: ");
char car = Global.keyboard.nextChar();
switch(car) {
    case 'r':
    case 'R':
        position += 1; //Or position++ if you prefer, but I'd use this approach
                       //just in case you want to do position += 5 in the future
                       //or better yet, position += dx, being dx an int that
                       //defines the range of a single movement.
        break;
    case 'l':
    case 'L':
        position -= 1; //Same as with right, but position -= dx;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Please, use r - R for (R)ight or l - L for (L)eft");
        break;
}
System.out.print(position);
```

Also, please note I changed your position updating. To adress your current question, `==` shouldn't be used to compare `Strings` since it compares references. Use `equals` instead.